# Decomposition of Delannoy Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

The Wolfram Mathworld [article for Delannoy Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DelannoyNumber.html) makes the following mention at the end:

> Amazingly, taking the Cholesky decomposition of the square array of $D(a,b)$, transposing, and multiplying it by the diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(2^{(-0/2)},2^{(-1/2)},2^{(-2/2)},...)$ gives the square matrix version of Pascal's triangle.

I find this quite fascinating and I've been looking for a proof and any further info/corollaries, but the article cites "personal communication" from 2005 for this statement and I've had no luck finding anything else.

I've verified numerically for small $n$ that this does indeed hold. I've also played around with it for a while, but I feel my knowledge of Delannoy Numbers and combinatorics is too little to find a proof.

I'd like to look into this further, so I'm wondering if anyone has a proof of this or knows of a source with more info towards a proof and further corollaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a pretty direct consequence of one of the formulae mentioned on your link:

$$D(n,k)=\sum_{d=0}^n 2^d\binom{k}{d}\binom{n}{d}=\sum_{d=0}^N \left(2^{d/2}\binom{k}{d}\right)\left(2^{d/2}\binom{n}{d}\right)$$

for any $N\ge \min(n,k)$. Now if we consider the $N\times N$ lower-triangular matrix $L_{ij}=2^{j/2} \binom{i}{j}$, note that the previous identity can be written as $D=LL^T$.

Comment: I didn't think to split up the summand.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There exists a similar result for Pascal triangle presented at 45°, whose Cholesky factorization gives as well the classical (line-column) presentation of the Pascal triangle. This result could be considered with (controversial) "infinite matrices", a concept that, fortunately, we do not need because, whatever the finite dimensions we give to the matrices, we have an exact statement ; for example, il we restrict our scope to $5 \times 5$ matrices, we have :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
   1&2&3&4&5\\
   1&3&6&10&15\\
   1&4&10&20&35\\
   1&5&15&35&70
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
1& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
1& 2& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 3& 3& 1& 0\\
1& 4& 6& 4& 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 1& 2& 3& 4\\
0& 0& 1& 3& 6\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 4\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

More results [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix), [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/papers/pascal-work.pdf) and [here](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~giacomo.dellariccia/Table%20of%20contents/BrawerPirovino1992.pdf). The similarity with Delannoy paths comes from the fact that, when "Delannoy directions" are restricted to North and East (without diagonals), the number of minimal paths in a rectangular grid from its South-West to its North-East vertex $n \times p$ is $\binom{n+p}{p}$ coefficients.

Comment: very interesting. Thanks for the links!